# setting up trees of renderers in structlog

Tags: python, json, rendering, stdout, structlog

How would I configure `structlog` such that all messages including above `info` would go to `stdout` using a `KeyValueRenderer` while *all* logging would also go to a file using a `JSONRenderer`?

**note:** I only want to use structlog, no standard library stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`structlog` doesn't do this out of the box, you'll need to write the required code yourself. `structlog` is built in a way to make this straightforward and it should be around a dozen of LoC.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using standard library logging, this should be rather straightforward using configuration only. Check out the logging configuration example in http://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html#rendering-using-structlog-based-formatters-within-logging – ISTM it does something quite similar?

Comment: I'm really looking for a structlog-only solution. How do I filter based on level in a structlog-only world? How do I render to multiple destinations in a structlog-only world?

Comment: Where are your log levels coming from then? `structlog` doesn’t really have a concept of them (but easily added of course). What you can do is to 1. use a pass thru formatter (`lambda _, __, ed: ed` should do) and write your own logger (the thing that gets passed as `logger_factory`) that acts on the event_dict. Since you mix output and formatting, there's no way around it sadly.

Comment: Hmm, `structlog` loggers have "level"-based names, surprised level-based filtering isn't included. Also surprised there's no way to have different formats written to different destinations. Would it be fair to say the answer to my question above is that "you can't, unless you write it yourself"?

Comment: Yes, *but also*: `structlog` is built in a way to make that straightforward. What we’re talking here about is a dozen of LoC. The level-y names are basically just to make it mostly drop-in. Might not have been the best idea in hindsight.